# Using Riemann sums to show that $\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i = \log{n} +c+O(1/n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms, riemann-sum, harmonic-numbers

I want to show that there exists a constant $c$ such that:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i = \log{n} +c+O(1/n)
$$

I am thinking about Riemann sums. Any hints on that?

Comment: Write $$\log n = \int_1^n \frac{dx}{x}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer: it is not sufficient to prove that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}(H_n-\log n)$ exists.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio No, but that is the first step. And looking at the tail, one sees the $O(1/n)$ remainder.

Comment: Are you considering Riemann sums approach only?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal No. It's just that when I saw it I thought that it is related with Riemann sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Abel's summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) is the standard tool:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}&=&1+\int_{1}^{N}\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x^2}\,dx=1+\log N-\int_{1}^{N}\frac{\{x\}}{x^2}dx\\&=&\log N+\left(1-\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\{x\}}{x^2}dx\right)+\int_{N}^{+\infty}\frac{\{x\}}{x^2}.\end{eqnarray*}\tag{1}$$
Since $\{x\}\in[0,1)$, the last term is positive and bounded by $\int_{N}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{1}{N}.$

Answer (score 1):

Consider integral $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{x} dx=\log n$. Divide $[1,n]$ to $n$ subintervals in form $[k,k+1]$ for $k=1,2, \cdots, n-1$. You have two inequalities:

$$\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{x} dx = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\int_{i}^{i+1}\frac{1}{x}dx \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i}$$

And

$$\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{x} dx = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\int_{i}^{i+1}\frac{1}{x}dx \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i+1}$$

It's because for $x \in [k,k+1]$ you have $\frac{1}{k} \geq \frac{1}{x} \geq \frac{1}{k+1}$.

Comment: The first inequality is $\frac{1}{i+1}$ and the second one $\frac{1}{i}$ in the sum on the right hand side right?

Comment: Using those inequalities I reach:
$$
1/n\leq \sum_{i=1}^n1/i -\log{n}\leq 1/n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i(i+1)}
$$
Am I on the right direction?

Comment: But the last term is equal to $1/n+1-1/n=1$.

Comment: But $1/n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i(i+1)}=1/n+(1-1/n)=1$

Comment: Yes, you're right, because $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i(i+1)} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i(i+1)} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^2} =\frac{\pi^2}{6} $.

Comment: Proving that the hypothetical constant is bounded by $\zeta(2)$ does not prove that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}(H_n-\log n)$ exists, however.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach. First the sum admits the closed form

> $$ S = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i} = \psi(n+1)+\gamma, $$

where $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) and $\psi(x)$ is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function). Now jut use the [well known expansion of the $\psi(x)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)

> $$ \psi(x) = \ln(x) - \frac{1}{2x} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right).$$

Note that your constant $c$ can be determined exactly.